# Least annoying way to check auto updates in native app

Tags: c++, windows, native

What would be the best approach?

So far I can think of:

- Super small WinMain exe in HKLM\Run that checks, say, twice a day
- Windows service that checks, say, twice a day
- Scheduled tasks (can't seem to find a way to start GUI task via user account, desktop isolation and stuff)
- Application itself (doesn't work if there are multiple exes, for example, as in  Sysinternals Suite, many, many applications, one large suite)

Anything else? I want it to stay native and avoid being obtrusive or delay startup of the cold boot.

Comment: "Windows service" would be one of the things that would make me uninstall your program right away and would make you receive a hate mail. It's the kind of thing you just don't do, unless you have the incredible arrogance to believe (like some major software companies) that you own the user's computer, not them. Checking for an update at program start is acceptable, but this needs to be configurable. If it cannot be turned off, it will annoy the hell out of many users (those with dialup at the very least).

Comment: You already have 4 approaches you can make work.  Why do you need more?  We can't help you choose, you didn't say anything about your app, its usage and the kind of user that runs it.

Comment: The expected user base ranges from computer illiterates to gurus. And I want to notify the user about functional and security updates. Idea is to avoid IE6-forever edition. So that users even with limited computer skills would still be on the latest version. All 4 approaches seem hostile to some part of user base in my opinion, and I honestly don't know what's the best approach.

Comment: What about making a configure option within the program to check for updates automatically once per week (enabled by default, if you will), and if that option is turned off, show a little, non-intrusive notification bar in the program's window every 8 weeks (like the "Do you want Firefox to save the password for this page?") that reminds the user. That way, it is not nearly as hostile but you know that 30-50% will be up-to-date within a week, 99% will be up-to-date within half a year (after getting 3 reminders), and ... screw the remaining 1% :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Larry Osterman [posted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/08/20/applet-mitigations-updaters.aspx) something about this on his blog awhile back. The basic points:

- Twice a day is WAY too often to check for updates
- Windows Service is a terrible idea
- So is a small constantly running WinMain
- Make sure the user can turn it off easily. Otherwise you're just going to annoy a large subset of your users

Answer (score -1):

Just don't do it. Period.

Today I uninstalled Trillian because it denied me to log on to the network as my "build was out of date". TortoiseSVN annoys me rather often with popups about new version being available, and had I known about an alternative, I would also have uninstalled TortoiseSVN and installed something less annoying. If I have a program that works and does what I need, and I do not stumble upon any of its bugs, then I have no reason to upgrade, thank you.

The only valid reason for notifying the user about new updates being available are security updates, and then you could send out notifications via email or RSS feed. If I care about it, I will register my email address upon download or subscribe to the RSS feed.

Comment: You can disable TortoiseSVN's version check in the 'General' section of the settings.

Comment: User wants to do it. You annoyance with Trillian and TortoiseSVN is not pertinent. If you want to make that argument, that's what comments are for.

Comment: Users want to do it? Citation needed.

Comment: Actually I do like when applications I use often report me about upgrades. FireFox, Skype, if they wouldn't, I would probably be running old unsecure versions and such. But some applications annoy me. And I cant get a grip on why, and again, my view is subjective, so I wanted to get some feedback.